# Reference other columns by name fragment in mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr

To visualize the problem, let's assume I have a dataset `data` in R with the following columns:

- factor
- param
- T1_g1
- T2_g1
- T1_g2
- T2_g2

I want to perform an operation on a subset of columns:

```r
data_final <- data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(T1, T2), funs(if(param > 100) {
    . * T(n)_g1 
  } else {
    . * T(n)_g2
  }
```

How do I reference the correct column name in the expression `T(n)_g1` so it fetches data from `T1_g1` and `T2_g1`, respectively, while mutating?

(in a real case scenario, I have much more columns and conditions, hence manually typing all possible cases is not an option)

Comment: Are there more than two such columns `T1` and `T2`, or are you trying to generalize this? If it's just two, the easiest solution is likely `mutate` with `if_else`.

Comment: I am trying to generalize - there is a high number of such columns. Thanks for the answer below, @r2evans!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` needs a single comparison, but since this will be a vector, you need `if_else` (or `ifelse`). I don't know that you can (easily) dynamically determine the other column names based on the to-be-changed name within a quick `mutate*` interface. A quick hack could be:

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    T1 = if_else(param > 100, T1_g1, T1_g2) * T1,
    T2 = if_else(param > 100, T2_g1, T2_g2) * T2
  )
```

but this only works if you have a small/static list of `T*` variables to modify.

If there is a dynamic (or just "high") number of these `T*` variables, one method includes reshaping the frame to a longer format. (One could argue that a long format might be a better fit for this regardless, so I'll step you through wide-long-mutate as well as wide-long-mutate-wide.)

Some data:

```
x <- data_frame(
  param = c(1L,50L,101L,150L),
  T1 = 1:4,
  T2 = 5:8,
  T1_g1 = (1:4)/10,
  T1_g2 = (1:4)*10,
  T2_g1 = (5:8)/10,
  T2_g2 = (5:8)*10
)
x
# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#   param    T1    T2 T1_g1 T1_g2 T2_g1 T2_g2
#   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     5   0.1    10   0.5    50
# 2    50     2     6   0.2    20   0.6    60
# 3   101     3     7   0.3    30   0.7    70
# 4   150     4     8   0.4    40   0.8    80
```

First, the first reshaping:

```
x %>%
  gather(k, v, -param) %>%
  mutate(
    num = sub("^T([0-9]+).*", "\\1", k),
    k   = sub("^T[0-9]+(.*)", "T\\1", k)
  ) %>%
  spread(k, v)
# # A tibble: 8 x 5
#   param num       T  T_g1  T_g2
#   <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 1         1   0.1    10
# 2     1 2         5   0.5    50
# 3    50 1         2   0.2    20
# 4    50 2         6   0.6    60
# 5   101 1         3   0.3    30
# 6   101 2         7   0.7    70
# 7   150 1         4   0.4    40
# 8   150 2         8   0.8    80
```

What we've done is turned four rows with `3*n` columns with the `T#`, `T#_g1`, and `T#_g2` pattern, into just 3 columns but `n` times the number of rows. We preserve this `n` as another column (for now). This is arguably a good format to work with in general: `tidyverse` and notably `ggplot2` really likes data in this format, but there is likely more I don't know.

Now the full shebang (repeating the first few lines of code):

```
x %>%
  gather(k, v, -param) %>%
  mutate(
    num = sub("^T([0-9]+).*", "\\1", k),
    k   = sub("^T[0-9]+(.*)", "T\\1", k)
  ) %>%
  spread(k, v) %>%
  mutate(T = T * if_else(param > 100, T_g1, T_g2)) %>%
  gather(k, v, -param, -num) %>%
  mutate(k = if_else(grepl("^T", k), paste0("T", num, substr(k, 2, nchar(k))), k)) %>%
  select(-num) %>%
  spread(k, v)
# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#   param     T1 T1_g1 T1_g2     T2 T2_g1 T2_g2
#   <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 10       0.1    10 250      0.5    50
# 2    50 40       0.2    20 360      0.6    60
# 3   101  0.900   0.3    30   4.90   0.7    70
# 4   150  1.6     0.4    40   6.4    0.8    80
```

after the reshaping, your initial `mutate_at` concept is reduced to a single `mutate(T = ...)` call. The rest involves re-hydrating the width.

If your data is large, this might be a little cumbersome. Other solutions might involve manually determining the `T#` columns and manually doing the `ifelse` (outside of `mutate`).

Comment: Thanks a lot @r2evans for the comprehensive answer! The idea with reshaping the data is indeed a great approach.